# Call a javascript src url dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
```

I need to edit the `src` path dynamically. That is, I need to change the protocol(http/https) dynamically. How can I write the `src` which calls the `url` like, `location.protocol+ajax.googleapis.....`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do this dynamically - you can just say:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
```

Starting the `src` with the double-slash means "use whatever protocol the page is using."

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a script dynamically:

```
var src = 'myurl';
if (something) {
    src = 'other';
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = src;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```